# How can I create a symbolic link with a different name than the one with the original folder using gulp 3?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, symlink

Good,

I have a doubt, I need to make a symbolic link in the compilation folder of my angular project that goes towards the public folder of my api in laravel, I found the library vinyl-fs which had the option of creating symbolic links but I can not find the Way to give the name that I want to the link created, my current code is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var vfs = require('vinyl-fs');

gulp.task('symlink', function () {
   return gulp.src('../api/public')
     .pipe(vfs.symlink('./public/api'));
});
```

This code is currently generating the symbolic link inside the api folder but what I really need is that api is the symbolic link. I appreciate your collaboration.

PD Now try renaming it with gulp-rename but just create a folder with the name api